# How to show the only input field next to button within a loop

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a posts loop where each post has a comment box.Initially all comment box are hidden and when someone clicks on 'comments' button it should show the **comment field** for this user. I am having trouble to show specific comment box associated with the specific post. my code is as follows -

```
<div class="post-section" v-for="(post,index) in posts">
    <div class="media-content">{{post.body}}</div>

    <button @click="getComments(post, index)" class="btn btn-link"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>{{ post.total_comments }} Comments</button>

    <comment-input :postId="post.id"></comment-input>
</div>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                posts: [],
            }
        },

        created() {
            Post.all(posts => this.posts = posts);
        },

        methods: {
            getComments(post, index){
                axios.post('getcomments', {id: post.id})
                    .then(response => {
                        this.$set(this.posts, index, Object.assign({}, post, { comments: response.data }));
                    });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

When getComments(post, index) method executes i want to make visible the next comment-input only. Any help??

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what you wanted right? https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/smkw17Lk/

Comment: not exactly !! .. every post has a comment box associated. I want to hide all comment box initially. and when someone click on comment button (like ur fiddle) it will bring all comments and also make visible the comment box for this post only. I have simplified my code and shown above and also updated my question with an image. Its like google plus or facebook. I hope u got what i want. thanks @VamsiKrishna

Comment: @VamsiKrishna as alwayw u are legend!!  thanks a lot. it worked like charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra property called `toggleComments: false` to you `post` object. And use this to toggle the comments section including the comment text box which are grouped in a `<div>`.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/smkw17Lk/1/)

**html**

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(post,index) in posts">
        <p>{{post.body}}</p>
        <button @click="getComments(post, index)" class="btn btn-link">Show/Hide Comments</button>
        <div v-if="post.toggleComments">
            <textarea rows="1" cols="50" placeholder="comment here ..."></textarea>
            <div v-for='comment in post.comments'>
                <span class="comm">Commented by:{{comment.name}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        posts: [
            {id: 1, body: ' this is post #1'},
            {id: 2, body: ' this is post #2'},
            {id: 3, body: ' this is post #3'},
            {id: 3, body: ' this is post #4'},
            {id: 4, body: ' this is post #5'}
        ]
    },
    methods:{
        getComments(post, index){
            if(!post.comments){
                Vue.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
                .then(response => {
                    this.$set(this.posts, index, Object.assign({}, post, { comments: response.data }, { toggleComments: false}));
                },err => {
                    //handle errors
                });
            }
            post.toggleComments = !post.toggleComments;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach i can share is :

**html**

```
<div class="post-section" v-for="(post,index) in posts">
    <div class="media-content">{{post.body}}</div>

    <button @click="getComments(post, index)" class="btn btn-link"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>{{ post.total_comments }} Comments</button>

    <comment-input v-if="index == selectedPostIndex" :postId="post.id"></comment-input>
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                posts: [],
            }
        },

        created() {
            Post.all(posts => this.posts = posts);
        },

        methods: {
            getComments(post, index){
                axios.post('getcomments', {id: post.id})
                    .then(response => {
                        this.$set(this.posts, index, Object.assign({}, post, { comments: response.data }));
                    });

            this.selectedPostIndex = index;
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```